# Mariadb-10.0 install fails in boot2docker with "policy-rc.d denied execution" but works in Docker

Tags: vagrant, docker, boot2docker

I'm trying to setup a Vagrant + Docker based development environment on OS X 10.9. The first step is to create a container for MariaDB 10. However, for some reason, the Docker image won't build in the boot2docker VM on my OS X machine even though it works perfectly fine on Ubuntu 14.04.

I've tried boot2docker 1.2 with Docker 1.2 and 1.3 with 1.3 as well as all Phusion images from 0.9.10 to 0.9.15 , ubuntu:latest and Vagrant 1.6 and 1.6.5 without luck. Version 5.5 of MariaDB installs fine both on OS X and Ubuntu but I need the newer version.

I'm out of ideas on this one. Why does it work in Docker but not boot2docker and is it possible to fix the issue?

My `Vagrantfile` looks like this:

```
VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION = "2"
ENV["VAGRANT_DEFAULT_PROVIDER"] = "docker"

Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|
  config.vm.define "db" do |db|
    db.vm.provider "docker" do |d|
      d.name = "db"
      d.build_dir = "db"
    end
  end
end
```

And the accompanying `Dockerfile` in the relative `db` dir:

```
FROM phusion/baseimage:0.9.15

ENV HOME /root
CMD ["/sbin/my_init"]

RUN apt-get install software-properties-common
RUN apt-key adv --recv-keys --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 0xcbcb082a1bb943db
RUN add-apt-repository 'deb http://mirror.stshosting.co.uk/mariadb/repo/10.0/ubuntu trusty main'
RUN apt-get update
RUN DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -y mariadb-server

RUN apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/*
```

`vagrant up` terminates with:

```
...
Unpacking mariadb-server (10.0.14+maria-1~trusty) ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-16) ...
Setting up libaio1:amd64 (0.3.109-4) ...
Setting up libreadline5:amd64 (5.2+dfsg-2) ...
Setting up libdbi-perl (1.630-1) ...
Setting up libhtml-template-perl (2.95-1) ...
Setting up libmysqlclient18 (10.0.14+maria-1~trusty) ...
Setting up libdbd-mysql-perl (4.025-1) ...
Setting up libmariadbclient18 (10.0.14+maria-1~trusty) ...
Setting up mariadb-client-core-10.0 (10.0.14+maria-1~trusty) ...
Setting up mariadb-client-10.0 (10.0.14+maria-1~trusty) ...
Setting up mariadb-server-core-10.0 (10.0.14+maria-1~trusty) ...
Setting up mariadb-server-10.0 (10.0.14+maria-1~trusty) ...
invoke-rc.d: policy-rc.d denied execution of stop.
dpkg: error processing package mariadb-server-10.0 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mariadb-server:
 mariadb-server depends on mariadb-server-10.0 (= 10.0.14+maria-1~trusty); however:
  Package mariadb-server-10.0 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package mariadb-server (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.19-0ubuntu6.3) ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-16) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mariadb-server-10.0
 mariadb-server
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: I got this problem, too.

Answer (score 0):

I catch this error when my vagrant virtual mashine have *very low RAM*.